# return in function does not return but hang

Tags: node.js, express

In my nodejs 10.16.0 and express 4.16.4 app, there is a method `sendVcode1` which sends out SMS message and return with `success` or `failed to send`:

```
sendVcode1:async function(vcode, cell, cell_country_code) {

    switch(process.env.sms) {
        case "nexmo" :
            const nexmo = new Nexmo({
                apiKey: process.env.nexmoApiKey,
                apiSecret: process.env.nexmoApiSecret
            }, { debug: true });        

            nexmo.message.sendSms(process.env.nexmo_sender_number, cell_country_code + cell, vcode, {type: 'unicode'}, async (err, result) => {
                console.log("vcode in nexmo : ", vcode);
                if(err){
                    console.error("Vcode failed to send : ", err.message);
                    return 'failed to send';   
                }else{
                    console.log("successfully sent vcode");
                    return 'success';                   
                }              
            });

    };

},
```

Here is the calling code for the method above:

```
const result = await helper.sendVcode1(vcode, user.cell, user.cell_country_code)
    console.log("code send result : ", result);
    if(result === 'success') {...}
```

If the method `sendVcode` returns, then there should be console output `code send result ...`. But in console output, the app hangs after `successfully sent vcode` in method `sendVcode1` and nothing further. It seems that the `return "success"` never returns. What is wrong with the method `sendVcode1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because *nexmo.message.sendSms* function executes callback function, so you can try defining a generic method called sendSms and wrap the **nexmo.message.sendSms** function within a **promise**. After that you can call that generic function, pass the arguments and **return it inside sendVcode1 async function** with **await** keyword so it will wait for the result, like;

```js
function sendSms(nexmo, vcode, user.cell, user.cell_country_code){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    nexmo.message.sendSms(process.env.nexmo_sender_number, cell_country_code + cell, vcode, {type: 'unicode'}, async (err, result) => {
         console.log("vcode in nexmo : ", vcode);
         if(err){
           console.error("Vcode failed to send : ", err.message);
           resolve('failed to send');   
         }else{
           console.log("successfully sent vcode");
           resolve('success');                   
        }              
     });
   });
}

sendVcode1:async function(vcode, cell, cell_country_code) {
  switch(process.env.sms) {
    case "nexmo" :
       const nexmo = new Nexmo({
          apiKey: process.env.nexmoApiKey,
          apiSecret: process.env.nexmoApiSecret
       }, { debug: true });        

       return await sendSms(nexmo, vcode, cell, cell_country_code)
   }
}
```

Comment: `onuriltan` perfect answer I am looking for. Turning callback into a promise was what I had missed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sendVcode1` code returns a promise that returns immediately

does `nexmo.message.sendSms` return anything? It receives a callback as its last argument, unless that function returns a promise that forwards whatever is returned inside the callback, you won't get your `success`/`failed to send` in your outer promise.